# What is the most effective way of printing Arraylist of string array in Jsp?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, arraylist

There is an ArrayList which contains String arrays . Each string array contains values of each row. I want to print this in JSP. I tried printing it directly from servlet,its working but it is very slow since there is a lot of data.How to do this in JSP EL ?

```
public void printTableData(List<String[]> dataTable, PrintWriter out) {
        System.out.println(dataTable);
        out.println("<table border='1'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.get(0).length; j++) {
            out.println("<th>" + dataTable.get(0)[j] + "</th>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
        if (dataTable.size() > 1)
            for (int i = 1; i < dataTable.size(); i++) {
                out.println("<tr>");
                for (int j = 1; j < dataTable.get(i).length; j++) {
                    out.println("<td>" + dataTable.get(i)[j] + "</td>");

                }
                out.println("</tr>");
            }
        out.println("</table>");
    }

}
```

Comment: dataTable.forEach(System.out::println); i used lambdas here..or use iterator.

Comment: what do you mean by "lots of data"? thousands of rows? if it is the case, then this is your problem, you should "paginate" the results.
Anyway, a good java profiler will greatly help you to find where the time is lost

Comment: Look at how Google did it. It's called "filtering" and "pagination". They don't show all those gazillion Internet results at once in a single page. Webbrowsers simply don't chew that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass the data to your request.
Create a table header after:

```
<table class="your_class">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>More</th>
            <th>Other</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

then iterate over elements with `<for:each>`:

```
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="data">
            <tr class="your_class">
                <td>${data.attribute1}</td>
                <td>${data.attribute2}</td>
                <td>${data.attribute3}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The number of columns is not constant. It changes everytime.

Comment: and? use `c:if` and nest the `for:each`to achieve same results than in java, we will give you the tools, but not make you the work

Comment: You forgot to strip off irrelevant ng related classes and mention potential XSS attack holes in your untested approach.

Comment: @Jordi I didn't ask for the work. Just wanted to mention that you misunderstood the problem. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @LakshminathanLaky nope, you misunderstood the solutiion, if you can achieve it in java, you can do it in html...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the Strings will improve your performance.

```
public void printTableData(List<String[]> dataTable, PrintWriter out) {
    System.out.println(dataTable);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<table border='1'>\n");
    sb.append("<tr>\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.get(0).length; j++) {
        sb.append("<th>");
        sb.append(dataTable.get(0)[j]);
        sb.append("</th>\n");
    }
    sb.append("</tr>\n");
    if (dataTable.size() > 1)
        for (int i = 1; i < dataTable.size(); i++) {
            sb.append("<tr>\n");
            for (int j = 1; j < dataTable.get(i).length; j++) {
                sb.append("<td>");
                sb.append(dataTable.get(i)[j]);
                sb.append("</td>\n");

            }
            sb.append("</tr>\n");
        }
    sb.append("</table>\n");
    out.println(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was how to iterate in JSP...So...

- First you need to add list into request attribute:

  ```
  request.setAttribute("list", dataTable)
  ```
- Then you can iterate in jsp using `c:forEach` tag

  ```
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="entry">
      <!-- iterate here using ${entry} -->
  </c:forEach>
  ```

You can also use `varStatus="loop"`, if you're using JSP 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I go with Bazz answer. The below code should work fine. You need to add the listName model in request attribute.

```
<c:forEach var="listVar" items="${listName}">
<option value ="10"><c:out value="${listVar.attribute}"/></option>
```